# jQuery Conflict(?) when Adding & Removing li Elements

Tags: jquery

I have a table structure like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li class="check"></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li class="check"></li>
        <li class="check"></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My goal is, on click within a table cell, another li element is added to the single ul within each cell.  When clicking ON the li element, the last li in the cell's ul is removed.

Here is the jq I tried:

```
$(document).on("click", "table tr td", function() {
   var parul = $(this).children("ul");
   $('<li class="check">&nbsp;</li>').appendTo(parul);
});

$(document).on("click", "li.check", function(){
   $(this).siblings(":last").remove();
});
```

The table is being generated by jQ dynamically, so I'm trying to avoid using IDs in my selectors.  Also why I'm using .on(), since as I understand, it will apply to LIs that don't necessarily exist yet (please correct me if I'm understanding that incorrectly!).

I've found that the above 2 functions work **independently**, but when I uncomment both of them, only the "adding" function works, the remove doesn't.

I'm new to jQ, so this is a real mystery.  If there's a totally different solution that accomplishes the same goal, I wouldn't mind, but for learning purposes, I'd also like to understand why my code isn't working as I expected.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I try out your code at http://jsfiddle.net/a3J4Y/, I get the expected behavior -- namely, both handlers are run, and the last LI is removed and then added in rapid succession.

Comment: Also: be aware that removing the last sibling LI can have unexpected results if the LI you're clicking already *is* the last one -- namely, the "last sibling" is now the second-to-last LI in the list.

Comment: @mblase75 I just added some sequential id's to a bunch of LIs and I see what you mean when clicking on last li.  I'm currently also unable to remove the last li.  All of the LIs are equivalent. Is there a better way to do this so I can always assure that if there is a li in the table cell's ul, it will be able to be removed?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try: `$(this).parent().children().last().remove()`

Comment: @mblase75 thanks for that.  It accomplishes what I want and it's easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the `li`, the `td` registers a click as well.  You need to add `stopPropagation()` on the `li` handler:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "li.check", function(e) {
        $(this).siblings(":last").remove();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "table tr td", function() {
        var parul = $(this).children("ul");
        $('<li class="check">&nbsp;</li>').appendTo(parul);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uLCRd/

This will prevent the second handler from being called once the `li` click is handled.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works as I expect and I learned something too.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find this will work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/6BhKs/2/

Relevant JS Code:

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
   var parul = $(this).children("ul");
   $('<li class="check">LI TAG</li>').appendTo(parul);
});

$("table").on("click", "li", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).siblings(":last").remove();
});
```

When using on or delegate your target element (in your example document, in mine table) should be as close to the element you are listening for events as possible for performance reasons.

In the fiddle i added css and text to make the element "visible" for demo purposes.

Comment: Note that `.delegate()` has been superseded by `.on()` in jQuery 1.7+

Comment: been using moo for the last 6 mo at the day job ;)

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  New to jq, but never too soon to think about performance.